# sp_send_dbmail Incorrect syntax near '<'

Tags: html, sql, sp-send-dbmail

I'm having a problem sending a HTML formatted email from SQL server.

With the following section of code I get a `"Line 1, incorrect syntax near '<'"` error.

```
SET @tableHTML =
    '<H1>Progress Report</H1>' +
    '<table border="1">' +
    '<tr>' +
                '<th>Project Name</th>' +
                '<th>Platform</th>' +
                '<th>Due By</th>' +
                '<th>Current Status</th>' +
                '<th>Current State</th>' +
    '</tr>' +
    CAST (  
                ( 
                        SELECT
                                td = [Project Name],    ' ',
                                td = Platform,  ' ',
                                td = [Due By],  ' ',
                                td = [Current Status],  ' ',
                                td = [Current State],   ' '
    FROM [dbo].[table_name]
    ORDER BY [Current Status] DESC
    FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE
              ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    '</table>' ;
```

I cant seem to pin it to anything in particular? Any Idea's?

Thanks

Update 1:

Ok I've run the code in a debug session and have checked the contents of @tableHTML, the contents looks fine and it gets populated with the expected data from my Table.

Meaning the errors coming in from somewhere else, so I've copied the whole query this time.

```
DECLARE @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @tableHTML =
    '<h1>Progress Report</h1>' +
    '<table border="1">' +
    '<tr>' +
                '<th>Project Name</th>' +
                '<th>Platform</th>' +
                '<th>Due By</th>' +
                '<th>Current Status</th>' +
                '<th>Current State</th>' +
    '</tr>' +
    CAST 
        (   
                ( 
                        SELECT
                                td = [Project Name],    '',
                                td = Platform,  '',
                                td = [Due By],  '',
                                td = [Current Status],  '',
                                td = [Current State],   ''
    FROM [dbo].[table_name]
    ORDER BY [Current Status] DESC
    FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE
              ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    '</table>';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'db_mail_account',
    @recipients = 'example@example.com',
    @subject = 'Daily Project Tracking Report',
    @query = @tableHTML,
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Nothing stands out.  I would suggest that you remove one line at a time and figure out what is causing hte error.

Comment: Ok, so doing as suggested didn't really throw anything obvious up, so I decided to delve a bit deeper and watch the output in real time. Please see the update on my original post for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want `@tableHTML` to be the body of the email, but you're passing it in as `@query`, which has to contain valid SQL, hence the error.

Try using `@body` instead:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'db_mail_account',
    @recipients = 'example@example.com',
    @subject = 'Daily Project Tracking Report',
    @body = @tableHTML,
    @body_format = 'HTML';
```

Comment: Done and fixed, thanks. Quick follow up question that has now been thrown up. If the table contains a null value in one column, currently the row gets moved to the left, which breaks the tables formatting (as incorrect entries are listed under the wrong column headers). Any idea's on how to prevent this happening?

Comment: For each field, wrap it in a `COALESCE()` call, e.g. `td = COALESCE([Project Name], ''),    '',`

Comment: Can you mark this answer as accepted if you're happy with it? http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer